# Recyclerview not properly in scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am developing android app using recyclerview. But when i am using `compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'` in build.gradle. It is not working proper. When scrolling the contents are coming correctly but the design are like that shown in image 2.
It is working proper on when using `compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`. 
My android studio version is 3.0.

I think the problem in `build.gradle`

My code is shown in below

***build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "c.recycle3"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

*content_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="c.recycle3.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*movie_list_row.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/genre"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:textColor="@color/year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MoviesAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            Movie movie = movieList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    prepareMovieData();
}
private void prepareMovieData() {
    Movie movie = new Movie("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Action & Adventure", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Inside Out", "Animation, Kids & Family", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens", "Action", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Shaun the Sheep", "Animation", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("The Martian", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation", "Action", "2015");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Up", "Animation", "2009");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Star Trek", "Science Fiction", "2009");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("The LEGO Movie", "Animation", "2014");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Iron Man", "Action & Adventure", "2008");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Aliens", "Science Fiction", "1986");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Chicken Run", "Animation", "2000");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Back to the Future", "Science Fiction", "1985");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Raiders of the Lost Ark", "Action & Adventure", "1981");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Goldfinger", "Action & Adventure", "1965");
    movieList.add(movie);

    movie = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy", "Science Fiction & Fantasy", "2014");
    movieList.add(movie);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

*DividerItemDecoration.java*

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};
public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;
public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;
private Drawable mDivider;
private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
}
```

*Movie.java*

```
public class Movie {
private String title, genre, year;

public Movie() {
}

public Movie(String title, String genre, String year) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(String year) {
    this.year = year;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}
}
```

*MoviesAdapter.java*

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Movie> moviesList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView title, year, genre;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        genre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        year = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.year);
    }
}


public MoviesAdapter(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    this.moviesList = moviesList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movie = moviesList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
    holder.genre.setText(movie.getGenre());
    holder.year.setText(movie.getYear());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return moviesList.size();
}
}
```

*RecyclerTouchListener.java*

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

I got the code from https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuWIV.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwT77.png)

Please help me.

Comment: show your layout and adapter code for recyclerview

Comment: changes to recycler about handling wrap_content and match_parent were made between those version iirc

Comment: @NileshRathod i have added full source code.

Comment: @poss The result is showing as same.

Comment: @Fazilfazi any reason why your movie row is `android:layout_height="match_parent"` ?

Comment: @poss i got the answer thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this change your `RelativeLayout` to`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
of **movie_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:focusable="true"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:paddingTop="10dp"
   android:paddingBottom="10dp"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
   android:orientation="vertical">
```